# How to align a Canva child on it's middle to specific coordinates?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I receive some coordinates from my ViewModel and I need to have one child of my WPF Canvas with its center on those coordinates.

How can I achieve this? I tried several RenderTransform, but I'm unable to have the desired effect.

```
<Canvas>
   <SomeControl Canvas.Left="{Binding ToolBarHorizontalPosition}" Canvas.Top="{Binding ToolBarVerticalPosition}"/>
</Canvas>



public MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged{
   public double ToolBarHorizontalPosition {get;set;}
   public double ToolBarVerticalPosition{get;set;}

   public void SomeUpdater(){
      ToolBarHorizontalPosition  = ...;
      ToolBarVerticalPosition= ...;
      // Raise property changed
   }
}
```

The thing is that the control will have a dynamic size(it's content will grow), so I cannot compute directly the toolbar position to reference the left/right(because I don't know the width).

Is there a way to make this in the XAML?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found a solution, using a converter that manage to get the position from the ViewModel and the `ActualWidth`:

```
public class CenterValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length != 2)
        {
            return null;
        }

        double originalPosition = (double)values[0];
        double size = (double)values[1];
        return originalPosition - (size / 2);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
        Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then in my XAML for center on the X Axis:

```
<Canvas>
   <SomeControl Name="SomeControl" Canvas.Top="{Binding ToolBarVerticalPosition}">
      <Canvas.Left>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CenterValuerConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ToolBarHorizontalPosition"/>
            <Binding ElementName="SomeControl" Path="ActualWidth"/>
         </MultiBinding>
      </Canvas.Left>
   </SomeControl>
</Canvas>
```